# KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]") when calculating average metrics after Cross Validation

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to calculate some average metrics after performing cross validation.
The function that do that is the following one:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from numpy import mean
from numpy import std
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

    # Returns average confusion matrix, average accuracy 
    # and average standard deviation after all the cross-validation runs
    def get_average_metrics(model,cv,X_fss,y):
        conf_matrix_list_of_arrays = []
        scores = []
        for train_index, test_index in cv.split(X_fss):
           X_train, X_test = X_fss[train_index], X_fss[test_index]
           y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
           score = model.fit(X_train, y_train).score(X_test, y_test)
           conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, model.predict(X_test))
           scores.append(score)
           conf_matrix_list_of_arrays.append(conf_matrix)
        # Average confusion matrix
        mean_of_conf_matrix_arrays = mean(conf_matrix_list_of_arrays, axis=0)
        # Average accuracy
        avg_score = mean(scores)
        # Average standard deviation
        std_score = std(scores)
        return avg_score,std_score,mean_of_conf_matrix_arrays
```

However, I get this error in `X_train, X_test = X_fss[train_index], X_fss[test_index]` line:

> KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([   1,    2,    4,    5,    6,    7,
> 9,   10,   11,   12,\n            ...\n            1620, 1621, 1622,
> 1623, 1624, 1625, 1626, 1627, 1629, 1630],\n           dtype='int64',
> length=1467)] are in the [columns]"

**Received funcion parameters**:

- model -> `logistic = LogisticRegression()`
- cv -> `cv = KFold(n_splits=10,shuffle=True, random_state=1)`
- X_fss -> a **Dataframe** of size (1631, 4)
- y -> a **Series** of size (1631,)

`X_fss` sample:

[image]

`y` sample:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it converting `X_fss` **Dataframe** into a **numpy array**:

```
X_fss = X_fss.to_numpy()
```